# Minimal effort setup of Django for webdesigner

Tags: python, django, heroku

In the old world I had a pretty ideal development setup going to work together with a webdesigner. Keep in mind we mostly do small/fast projects, so this is how it worked:

- I have a staging site on a server (Webfaction or other)
- Designer accesses that site and edits templates and assets to his satisfaction
- I SSH in regularly to checkin everything into source control, update files from upstream, resolve conflicts

It works brilliantly because the designer does not need to learn git, python, package tools, syncdb, migrations etc. And there's only the one so we don't have any conflicts on staging either.

Now the problem is in the new world under Heroku, this is not possible. Or is it? In any way, I would like your advice on a development setup that caters to those who are not technical.

Comment: To understand your question, why have you migrated from webfactional to Heroku? Have you migrated your staging site or your production site? How your designer accessed to webfactional site?

Comment: Setting up a new site seemed easier once using the default layout. Free quota also help getting started.

Comment: I may be looking for something like this for django: http://pow.cx/

Answer (score 0):

How about a static 'showcase' site where all possible UI elements, templates, etc are shown using dummy content. The designer can connect, edit stuff and you merge in the changes in the end. Another option would be a test server with the full application running (kind of like you did it before) but with the option to connect via FTP or whatever the designer prefers.

Comment: I wouldn't mind buying space on a server to facilitate this setup again, but I don't want to get into the hassle of configuring those things again. If there is a server based hosting for django that accepts a standard heroku layout, that would be great.

Comment: Otherwise, it could also be useful to modernize this setup and move it to the designer's computer, but I haven't found a way yet that takes few and not so painful steps.

Answer (score 0):

Why not store all of the assets on S3?

It sounds to me that they don't really need to be part of the application at all, but external resources that the application references.

Comment: That is one possible solution, but having editable live templates is the other (and more critical) part.